# Frequency response equalizer

Tags: fourier-analysis, signal-processing

I have $ H_{tot} (f) = e^{-i 2 \pi f T } $ if $ |f| < \frac{1}{2T} $ and ‘ it doesn’t matter ‘ if $ |f| > \frac{1}{2T} $  and $ H(f) = (1 + 2a cos (2 \pi f T )) e^{-i 2 \pi f T } $ and I have to find the frequency response of the equalizer. I know from theory that $ \frac{H_{tot} (f) }{H (f) } = H_{eq}(f) $ and I found that $ H_{eq } (f)  = \frac{1}{1 + 2acos(2 \pi f T } $. This is correct but now my book also write that this is also equal to $ \frac{1}{A_H (f) } rect (fT) $ 
Thank you !

Comment: So, 1/A_H(f) is just your solution. I guess rect(fT) is 1 for ft<1 and 0 otherwise? Then it would encode somehow the 'it doesn't matter' in the question...

Comment: Thank you so much for explain it to me !!! now I understand!

Comment: I would also guess that T is the sampling frequency. Then, by Shannon, you cannot really detect frequencies above 1/2T (simplified). So, essentially, it would make sense to set them to zero before doing further steps (don't transmit noise, save energy, keep the total power in the signal finite,...). Probably, then it should be rect(2fT), which is likely typo.